# Packaging and Deploying ASP.net applications for continuous delivery

Tags: asp.net, jenkins, msbuild, nuget

I come from a background of Java, PHP and NodeJS development.  I have successfully built continuous integration/continuous deployment environments using these languages based on a Linux Platform but now I am working in an environment with a mix of .NET web development and Java based web development.

I would like to build a CI/CD environment that shares tools and concepts as much as possible.  The workflow that has worked in the past and seems to be pretty standard is:

1. Check code into Git
2. Jenkins checks out the code, runs tests
3. Jenkins builds the code if tests pass
4. Jenkins builds a package. WAR file, RPM etc. and pushes it to an artifact repo, Maven, Yum repo, Artifactory, Nexus etc.
5. Jenkins deploys the package to a given environment by simply pulling the correct version of an artifact and pushing it to a given box.  I like to use Ansible or Puppet or some nice configuration management tool for this step and let that handle the versioning and environment specific changes.

I know Microsoft has built tools that can do similar things but I would like to keep things consistent across the organization and I feel like Jenkins is the gold-standard and has been battle tested for a hundred years while Microsoft’s CI tools are relatively new.

I am able to set up a Windows based Jenkins slave compile the code using the MSBuild plugin (This is an excellent tutorial if you are interested http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/january/continuous-deployment-with-jenkins-and-.net).  I am stuck on how to package the code.  I had thought NuGet would be a good choice for this but I can’t seem to find any guidance on building/deploying NuGet packages for ASP.NET applications and deploying them.  I prefer NuGet to something like the web application zip file as the packages are versioned.

Is NuGet the answer or is there something else out there that could support my needs or should I be altering my thinking for CI/CD in a Microsoft environment?

Comment: Nuget is a good place to start, create the packages by defining a nuspec file and runing 'nuget pack'. You could use powershell to push the packages and do the set up of your server (IIS etc) but I would recommend you take a look at Octopus Deploy

Comment: MSBuild can create packages for you that will be installed on IIS. It allows you to have different profiles with different settings for configuration (web.config) and IIS (*.pubxml files) You can then run those packages on your target machines with a tool like Ansible, including installation of IIS, msdeploy/webdeploy and other things you need.

Comment: Thank you both.  I started down the road of Nuget and then discovered the web deploy packages.  I would really like a combination of the two as I think it is critical to have a versioned package.  I was thinking a Chocalatey package that would wrap up the web deploy zip, param files and install script and kick off the install as part of the Chocalatey package.  It would need to know what environment we are in, dev/stage/prod.  Also, Ansible is really good at templatizing config files so something makes me think it should handle the environment specific details.  Confused as ever.